# Disable email cloaking in Joomla for one specific email address

Tags: html, email, joomla

I have an html5 form with an input field that contains a `placeholder` attribute, and I want to use an email address as the placeholder text. However Joomla is cloaking this email address, so the field shows up Javascript code instead of the original placeholder text.

Is it possible to disable email cloacking in Joomla for one specific email? I know about `{emailcloak=off}` but there are other email addresses in the page which should continue to be cloaked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `@` in the email address with `&#064;` or `&#64;` or `&#x00040;` or `&commat;`

Comment: It's the same, a bit old school maybe, but the zero is irrelevant.